# Should we merge Master to Release or vice versa?

Tags: git, github

Currently, in our project, we are checking in code to master branch. The release is approaching. We have branched out to as release-1.0 after dev freeze(stopping checking in code) is done. 
We have done thorough testing on release-1.0 branch deployed environments, after which we found few bugs. We fixed them. Here is my question...

**1. Should we checkIn these code fixes to master or release-1.0? I mean which is recommended and best practice to do?

 2. Based on the checking in branch, we will do merge to other branch. Right?

 3. Is there any other good practices to follow in this regard?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

- If you're fixing issues on release-1.0, you branch off and merge into that branch
- If you're doing development for future release, you branch off and merge into master
- You can and should merge release-1.0 down to master periodically
- When you're done working on release-1.0 and ready to deploy it, you can tag that with something like official-1.0 or something similar to indicate it represents an actual version

Ultimately this all boils down to which workflow you decide to use. This is more of a guideline than a rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you use branch-per-release, then a common practice would be to apply the fixes to new a branch, say `release-1.0-sp1` that branches off of `release-1.0` which is the exact version that you're trying to fix, and deploy your app again from the `release-1.0-sp1` branch.

Then, you'd *merge* (as in `git merge`) `release-1.0-sp1` into your development branch (`master` in your case).

A popular workflow is the [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) which might be what you're looking for in terms of good practices to follow.

> https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Answer (score 0):

- **tag** publish a new release (version)
- **hotfix** patch a release
- **release** prepare a new release
- **feature** prototype in isolation
- **master** represents the official release history
- **develop** latest state of the project, including the **feature** branches that are ready

See [this article](https://medium.com/@HendrikPrinsZA/gitflow-with-semver-dde625429aca) for more details and examples.